# Problem with QgsMapCanvas().zoomToSelection() when running from function

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, zoom, function

I have the following function which, when typed in to the python console line for line works fine, but when I use the function it gets as far as highlighting/selecting the accident (feature) but the `zoomToSelection()` statement doesn't appear to do anything.

```
def find_acc(layer, expression, scale = 2500):

    lay = core.QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layer)[0]
    canvas = QgsMapCanvas()

    request = core.QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expression)
    iter = lay.getFeatures(request)

    selection = [f for f in iter]

    if len(selection) == 1:
        print "Found accident"
        accident = selection[0]
    else:
        raise IOError, "More than 1 entry found"

    lay.setSelectedFeatures([accident.id()])
    canvas.zoomtoSelected()
    #canvas.zoomScale(scale) disabled to see if would make a difference - it didn't

    # added in afterwards
    canvas.refresh()
```

once imported in to QGIS I use the function `find_acc("accidents", "\"Police_ref\" = '0111XH30035'", 2500)`.

I tried again with `canvas.refresh()` after `zoomToSelected()` but that didn't help. Interestingly, despite the feature being highlighted on the map I can't use the keyboard shortcut `CTRL + J` or `View > Zoom to Selection` either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new canvas, not referencing the main window canvas.

Use `canvas = iface.mapCanvas()` instead of `canvas = QgsMapCanvas()`